# Sending request to Google not using Contacts API

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api

I was checking the API reports for Contact, Calendar and Tasks. I was surprised to see that the number of requests for Contacts API is 0 for last 28 days. However we synced thousands of contacts with Google everyday. Please refer screenshot attached.

From the stats it seems that the requests we are making to Google is NOT using Contacts API.

[image]

Overview of our application's google integration:

1. Our application is built on Ruby on Rails.
2. We are using 'google-contacts' gem (https://github.com/varunlalan/google-contacts) for syncing contacts.
3. We authenticate user using 'omniauth-google-oauth2' gem (https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2).
4. OAuth 2 scopes include - "userinfo.email, userinfo.profile, https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/"

Any reason why it is not making use of Contacts API or requests not being showed up in the reports?

Any help or inputs would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

just wanted to add that we're facing the same issue.

We've been using the Contacts API heavily (and we even got a 503 due to, it seems, exceeding the maximum requests/second) and yet the dashboard and the reports show 0% usage... which makes it a bit difficult to plan ahead!

After further investigation we have also seen that the per user quota is fixed at 10/user/second despite any changes to the config from the API console.

Also, the parameter quotaUser which is meant to enable developers to manage their quota more effectively is ignored.